# QuickFIX/J session API logon() call failed

Tags: quickfixj

Right now we are storing the session in map. So very first time , when we create  session,  it is possible that the session got created ,but due to some issue ,it immediately disconnected and logged out.
After some time, being the sessionId present in map, we are calling just lookup for that session and call logOn() . It should call my overridden logon() method which is not happening. Can anyone tell me the the possible clause and how to handle this ?when I see the logs, it's showing EndOfStream occurred,disconnecting.

Comment: Which overridden logon method? In your application? That one is only called if the logon was successful.

Comment: Please update question with these details and log excerpts.

Comment: Possible causes for end of stream: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60602710/4962355